# Does this quaternary quartic form primitively represent infinitely many sufficiently large powers?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $g(x,y,z,t)=(x+y+z+t)^4-a h(x,y)$ where $h(x,y) \in \{x^4,xy^3,x^2y^2\}$
and $a$ is integer.

> Does $g$ represent infinitely many powers $r^n$
>   with $n > 4$, $x+y+z+t,ah(x,y)$ take distinct values
>   and $x,y,z,t$ are coprime?

Appears to abc implies no when $g(x,y,z,t)$ and $h(x,y)$ are coprime,
unless something weird goes with the sizes of $x,y,z,t$.

The related question about $z^4-xy^3$ is easy since it is linear
in $x$.

Comment: If you substitute $z \leftarrow z-x-y-t$, then your form becomes $z^4 - a h(x,y)$, so it is really a ternary quartic.

Comment: @MichaelStoll Thank you! The question was stupid...